# Bomblab Phase 6 - reading assembly code

Tags: assembly

So I am doing a bomblab for school and I got through all the phases except the last phase 6.  The assignment is to read through the assembly code of a C program and try to figure out what it's doing in order to provide it the right input such that it won't blow up (AKA call the explode bomb function).  This one I've found particularly hard.  Here is what I know so far:

-This program needs 6 integers to be defused.  Anything else will explode.

-This program has at least 2 loops, possibly a 3rd, or an if/else in addition.

-The outer loop runs 5 times and is stored in %esi.

-The program may be traversing over linked lists or a 2d array.

You don't need to give me the answers - really any hints or help are appreciated.

Here is a dump of the assembly:

Dump of assembler code for function phase_6:

```
   0x08048d96 <+0>:     push   %ebp
   0x08048d97 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048d99 <+3>:     push   %edi
   0x08048d9a <+4>:     push   %esi
   0x08048d9b <+5>:     push   %ebx
   0x08048d9c <+6>:     sub    $0x5c,%esp
   0x08048d9f <+9>:     lea    -0x30(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048da2 <+12>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048da6 <+16>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048da9 <+19>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048dac <+22>:    call   0x804941b <read_six_numbers>
   0x08048db1 <+27>:    mov    $0x0,%esi
   0x08048db6 <+32>:    lea    -0x30(%ebp),%edi
   0x08048db9 <+35>:    mov    (%edi,%esi,4),%eax
   0x08048dbc <+38>:    sub    $0x1,%eax
   0x08048dbf <+41>:    cmp    $0x5,%eax
   0x08048dc2 <+44>:    jbe    0x8048dc9 <phase_6+51>
   0x08048dc4 <+46>:    call   0x80493c1 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048dc9 <+51>:    add    $0x1,%esi
   0x08048dcc <+54>:    cmp    $0x6,%esi
   0x08048dcf <+57>:    je     0x8048df3 <phase_6+93>
   0x08048dd1 <+59>:    lea    (%edi,%esi,4),%ebx
   0x08048dd4 <+62>:    mov    %esi,-0x4c(%ebp)
   0x08048dd7 <+65>:    mov    -0x4(%edi,%esi,4),%eax
   0x08048ddb <+69>:    cmp    (%ebx),%eax
   0x08048ddd <+71>:    jne    0x8048de4 <phase_6+78>
   0x08048ddf <+73>:    call   0x80493c1 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048de4 <+78>:    addl   $0x1,-0x4c(%ebp)
   0x08048de8 <+82>:    add    $0x4,%ebx
   0x08048deb <+85>:    cmpl   $0x5,-0x4c(%ebp)
   0x08048def <+89>:    jle    0x8048dd7 <phase_6+65>
   0x08048df1 <+91>:    jmp    0x8048db9 <phase_6+35>
   0x08048df3 <+93>:    mov    $0x0,%ebx
   0x08048df8 <+98>:    lea    -0x30(%ebp),%edi
   0x08048dfb <+101>:   jmp    0x8048e13 <phase_6+125>
   0x08048dfd <+103>:   mov    0x8(%edx),%edx
   0x08048e00 <+106>:   add    $0x1,%eax
   0x08048e03 <+109>:   cmp    %ecx,%eax
   0x08048e05 <+111>:   jne    0x8048dfd <phase_6+103>
   0x08048e07 <+113>:   mov    %edx,-0x48(%ebp,%esi,4)
   0x08048e0b <+117>:   add    $0x1,%ebx
   0x08048e0e <+120>:   cmp    $0x6,%ebx
   0x08048e11 <+123>:   je     0x8048e29 <phase_6+147>
   0x08048e13 <+125>:   mov    %ebx,%esi
   0x08048e15 <+127>:   mov    (%edi,%ebx,4),%ecx
   0x08048e18 <+130>:   mov    $0x804c4fc,%edx
   0x08048e1d <+135>:   mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x08048e22 <+140>:   cmp    $0x1,%ecx
   0x08048e25 <+143>:   jg     0x8048dfd <phase_6+103>
   0x08048e27 <+145>:   jmp    0x8048e07 <phase_6+113>
   0x08048e29 <+147>:   mov    -0x48(%ebp),%ebx
   0x08048e2c <+150>:   mov    -0x44(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048e2f <+153>:   mov    %eax,0x8(%ebx)
   0x08048e32 <+156>:   mov    -0x40(%ebp),%edx
   0x08048e35 <+159>:   mov    %edx,0x8(%eax)
   0x08048e38 <+162>:   mov    -0x3c(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048e3b <+165>:   mov    %eax,0x8(%edx)
   0x08048e3e <+168>:   mov    -0x38(%ebp),%edx
   0x08048e41 <+171>:   mov    %edx,0x8(%eax)
   0x08048e44 <+174>:   mov    -0x34(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048e47 <+177>:   mov    %eax,0x8(%edx)
   0x08048e4a <+180>:   movl   $0x0,0x8(%eax)
   0x08048e51 <+187>:   mov    $0x0,%esi
   0x08048e56 <+192>:   mov    0x8(%ebx),%eax
   0x08048e59 <+195>:   mov    (%ebx),%edx
   0x08048e5b <+197>:   cmp    (%eax),%edx
   0x08048e5d <+199>:   jle    0x8048e64 <phase_6+206>
   0x08048e5f <+201>:   call   0x80493c1 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e64 <+206>:   mov    0x8(%ebx),%ebx
   0x08048e67 <+209>:   add    $0x1,%esi
   0x08048e6a <+212>:   cmp    $0x5,%esi
   0x08048e6d <+215>:   jne    0x8048e56 <phase_6+192>
   0x08048e6f <+217>:   add    $0x5c,%esp
   0x08048e72 <+220>:   pop    %ebx
   0x08048e73 <+221>:   pop    %esi
   0x08048e74 <+222>:   pop    %edi
   0x08048e75 <+223>:   pop    %ebp
   0x08048e76 <+224>:   ret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to provide hints without giving the answers away.
Let me say that the first part is just checking some property of the six numbers.
For the second part, the hint is that the linked list is made up of nodes and each node also contains a value. Some procedure is applied to the list based on the input numbers and finally something is checked again.

Comment: OK so if I'm not mistaken the first part is checking whether any of the 6 numbers are the same, right?  So all 6 must be different numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your help Jester.  I'm making some progress.  I have a strong belief I would like you to confirm or deny. Are mine supposed to go in increasing order according to the hex value I find in each node?

Comment: Cancel that Jester.  I figured it out and got the solution.  Thank you for your hints.

Comment: Nice job, then! Cheers.

Comment: @user3334663 I'm doing the same bomblab and am stuck on this phase, could you guide me to the solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Jester Can you take a look at mine? I can't figure out how to access the last 3 nodes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35820389/solving-the-binary-bomb-phase-6?noredirect=1#comment59308551_35820389

Comment: @Jester, I figured out the first checks of this code. I noticed the linked list structure and found the struct node_t. There is a key, a left, and a right pointer. The key is not a number, but a const void*, how can I access the value being stored at each node? I think this should be the key to solving this phase.

Thanks!

Comment: Assembly does not have types. How do you know it's a `const void*`? Are you sure it's not a number? Anyway you can look at the value pointed to and the check the code how it's using the pointer.

Comment: I used the ptype command and guessed that the variable type as node_t. So when I inspected I got the types of each part of the struct. I was also able to get the offsets using /o with the same command.