# BombLab Phase 6

Tags: assembly, decompiling

This a homework assignment. I think I've managed to figure it out yet for some reason my solution does not work.

So there is a linked_list of 6 nodes and my answer is a string of 6 integers separated by a space. Numbers can only range from 1 to 6.From what I understood, it all boils down to sorting my list in descending order of node values and the answer is the order of nodes.

In my case, this happens to be:

```
node 6:     574
node 5:     385
node 4:     188
node 3:     675
node 2:     785
node 1:     952
```

Decreasing order: 1->2->3->6->5->4

Although sometimes, I get a different set of node values:

```
n1      -72
n2      17
n3      -93
n4      -68
n5      -127
n6      62
```

Decreasing order: 6->2->4->1->3->5

Yet for some reason, neither of these 6 digits work. I tried it in ascending order as well. I only ever receieve one of these two sets of node values. Following is the assembly dump of my code:

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_6:
   0x00000000004010b6 <+0>: push   %r14
   0x00000000004010b8 <+2>: push   %r13
   0x00000000004010ba <+4>: push   %r12
   0x00000000004010bc <+6>: push   %rbp
   0x00000000004010bd <+7>: push   %rbx
   0x00000000004010be <+8>: sub    $0x50,%rsp
   0x00000000004010c2 <+12>:    lea    0x30(%rsp),%rsi
   0x00000000004010c7 <+17>:    callq  0x401645 <read_six_numbers>
   0x00000000004010cc <+22>:    lea    0x30(%rsp),%r12
   0x00000000004010d1 <+27>:    mov    %r12,%r13
   0x00000000004010d4 <+30>:    mov    $0x0,%r14d
   0x00000000004010da <+36>:    mov    %r13,%rbp
   0x00000000004010dd <+39>:    mov    0x0(%r13),%eax
   0x00000000004010e1 <+43>:    sub    $0x1,%eax
   0x00000000004010e4 <+46>:    cmp    $0x5,%eax
   0x00000000004010e7 <+49>:    jbe    0x4010ee <phase_6+56>
   0x00000000004010e9 <+51>:    callq  0x4014e4 <explode_bomb>
   0x00000000004010ee <+56>:    add    $0x1,%r14d
   0x00000000004010f2 <+60>:    cmp    $0x6,%r14d
   0x00000000004010f6 <+64>:    je     0x40111a <phase_6+100>
   0x00000000004010f8 <+66>:    mov    %r14d,%ebx
   0x00000000004010fb <+69>:    movslq %ebx,%rax
   0x00000000004010fe <+72>:    mov    0x30(%rsp,%rax,4),%edx
   0x0000000000401102 <+76>:    cmp    %edx,0x0(%rbp)
   0x0000000000401105 <+79>:    jne    0x40110c <phase_6+86>
   0x0000000000401107 <+81>:    callq  0x4014e4 <explode_bomb>
   0x000000000040110c <+86>:    add    $0x1,%ebx
   0x000000000040110f <+89>:    cmp    $0x5,%ebx
   0x0000000000401112 <+92>:    jle    0x4010fb <phase_6+69>
   0x0000000000401114 <+94>:    add    $0x4,%r13
   0x0000000000401118 <+98>:    jmp    0x4010da <phase_6+36>
   0x000000000040111a <+100>:   lea    0x48(%rsp),%rcx
   0x000000000040111f <+105>:   mov    $0x7,%edx
   0x0000000000401124 <+110>:   mov    %edx,%eax
   0x0000000000401126 <+112>:   sub    (%r12),%eax
   0x000000000040112a <+116>:   mov    %eax,(%r12)
   0x000000000040112e <+120>:   add    $0x4,%r12
   0x0000000000401132 <+124>:   cmp    %rcx,%r12
   0x0000000000401135 <+127>:   jne    0x401124 <phase_6+110>
   0x0000000000401137 <+129>:   mov    $0x0,%esi
   0x000000000040113c <+134>:   jmp    0x401157 <phase_6+161>
   0x000000000040113e <+136>:   mov    0x8(%rdx),%rdx
   0x0000000000401142 <+140>:   add    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000000000401145 <+143>:   cmp    %ecx,%eax
   0x0000000000401147 <+145>:   jne    0x40113e <phase_6+136>
   0x0000000000401149 <+147>:   mov    %rdx,(%rsp,%rsi,2)
   0x000000000040114d <+151>:   add    $0x4,%rsi
   0x0000000000401151 <+155>:   cmp    $0x18,%rsi
   0x0000000000401155 <+159>:   je     0x40116c <phase_6+182>
   0x0000000000401157 <+161>:   mov    0x30(%rsp,%rsi,1),%ecx
   0x000000000040115b <+165>:   mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000000000401160 <+170>:   mov    $0x6033d0,%edx
   0x0000000000401165 <+175>:   cmp    $0x1,%ecx
   0x0000000000401168 <+178>:   jg     0x40113e <phase_6+136>
   0x000000000040116a <+180>:   jmp    0x401149 <phase_6+147>
   0x000000000040116c <+182>:   mov    (%rsp),%rbx
   0x0000000000401170 <+186>:   mov    0x8(%rsp),%rax
   0x0000000000401175 <+191>:   mov    %rax,0x8(%rbx)
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x0000000000401179 <+195>:   mov    0x10(%rsp),%rdx
   0x000000000040117e <+200>:   mov    %rdx,0x8(%rax)
   0x0000000000401182 <+204>:   mov    0x18(%rsp),%rax
   0x0000000000401187 <+209>:   mov    %rax,0x8(%rdx)
   0x000000000040118b <+213>:   mov    0x20(%rsp),%rdx
   0x0000000000401190 <+218>:   mov    %rdx,0x8(%rax)
   0x0000000000401194 <+222>:   mov    0x28(%rsp),%rax
   0x0000000000401199 <+227>:   mov    %rax,0x8(%rdx)
   0x000000000040119d <+231>:   movq   $0x0,0x8(%rax)
   0x00000000004011a5 <+239>:   mov    $0x5,%ebp
   0x00000000004011aa <+244>:   mov    0x8(%rbx),%rax
   0x00000000004011ae <+248>:   mov    (%rax),%edx
=> 0x00000000004011b0 <+250>:   cmp    %edx,(%rbx)
   0x00000000004011b2 <+252>:   jge    0x4011b9 <phase_6+259>
   0x00000000004011b4 <+254>:   callq  0x4014e4 <explode_bomb>
   0x00000000004011b9 <+259>:   mov    0x8(%rbx),%rbx
   0x00000000004011bd <+263>:   sub    $0x1,%ebp
   0x00000000004011c0 <+266>:   jne    0x4011aa <phase_6+244>
   0x00000000004011c2 <+268>:   add    $0x50,%rsp
   0x00000000004011c6 <+272>:   pop    %rbx
   0x00000000004011c7 <+273>:   pop    %rbp
   0x00000000004011c8 <+274>:   pop    %r12
   0x00000000004011ca <+276>:   pop    %r13
   0x00000000004011cc <+278>:   pop    %r14
   0x00000000004011ce <+280>:   retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: Would be better to show your source, so for those of us interested we could assemble it, but more important, see your comments to get an idea of your methodology. A GDB dump isn't very useful.

Comment: These assignments provide them with a binary that they have to reverse engineer.  There is no source code.  The GDB output is the best you'll get and what the assignment is based on... And it's very useful. :)

Comment: Still can't figure it out :( Halp! Already spent an entire day on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bomblab Phase 6 - reading assembly code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919819/bomblab-phase-6-reading-assembly-code)

Comment: I had to rotate my answer string right by 3 integers and it worked. Probably because my nodes were being shifted. Node 1,2,3 became Node 4,5,6.